# Reformatting Nested JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file which I want to convert to a CSV file:

```
[
  {
    "key-1": "value-1",
    "attributes": {
      "trait": "name",
      "value": "Some value"
    }
  },
  {
    "key-2": "value-2",
    "attributes": {
      "trait": "name",
      "value": "Some values"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to convert it into something like this:

```
[
  {
    "key-1": "value-1",
    "name": "Some value"
  },
  {
    "key-2": "value-2",
    "name": "Some values"
  }
]
```

How can I go about doing it using Python? I have tried using the `flatten_json` package but it gives me the following:

```
[
  {
    "key-1": "value-1",
    "attributes_0_trait": "name",
    "attributes_0_value": "Some value"
  },
  {
    "key-2": "value-2",
    "attributes_0_trait": "name",
    "attributes_0_value": "Some values"
  }
]
```

My current code:

```py
import json
import csv
from flatten_json import flatten

with open('_metadata.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

csv_file = open('metadata.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

count = 0

for data in json_data:
    data = flatten(data)
    keys = data.keys()
    if count == 0:
        csv_writer.writerow(data.keys())

    csv_writer.writerow(data.values())
    count += 1

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Your claimed expected output (which is a list of dicts) has nothing to do with CSV, which is what your code (and the first sentence of the question) appears to attempt to generate. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you provide more info on the structure of your data?

Comment: @blhsing I want the value from the first item in the attributes to become the key and the second value to become its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a thoroughly difficult transformation:

```
data = [
    {
        "key-1": "value-1",
        "attributes": {"trait": "name", "value": "Some value"},
    },
    {
        "key-2": "value-2",
        "attributes": {"trait": "name", "value": "Some values"},
    },
]

out_data = []

for item in data:
    item = item.copy()
    attrs = item.pop("attributes")
    item[attrs["trait"]] = attrs["value"]
    out_data.append(item)

print(out_data)
```

This prints out

```
[
  {'key-1': 'value-1', 'name': 'Some value'},
  {'key-2': 'value-2', 'name': 'Some values'},
]
```

If the items have more keys than `key-1` etc., those will be retained in the output dicts.

Comment: What if I have multiple JSON objects in the value of 'attributes'?

Comment: You should show example data like that, then. Do you mean they'd be a list of objects with trait/value keys?

Comment: I figured it out. Used a nested for loop to iterate over the values in 'attributes'. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
data = [
    {
        "key-1": "value-1",
        "attributes": {
            "trait": "name",
            "value": "Some value"
        }
    },
    {
        "key-2": "value-2",
        "attributes": {
            "trait": "name",
            "value": "Some values"
        }
    }
]

new_data = []

for entry in data:
    temp = {}
    for k, v in entry.items():
        if k.startswith('key'):
            temp[k] = v
        else:
            temp['name'] = v['value']
    new_data.append(temp)
print(new_data)
```

output

```
[{'key-1': 'value-1', 'name': 'Some value'}, {'key-2': 'value-2', 'name': 'Some values'}]
```

Comment: This assumes the `trait` key's value will always be `"name"`, doesn't it?

Comment: @AKX yes - anything wrong with this assumption ?

Comment: Why make such an assumption when you could just `temp[v['trait']] = v['value']`?

Comment: While your suggestion is more generic I think we should be able to present a "simple enough" solution . We both agree that the OP is a "novice" - (after all - it is a novice question). So I think sometimes "hard coded" solution is a better answer .

Comment: @AKX I wanted a more generic solution than a "harder coded" one.

Comment: @MRA1412 My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69359597/51685 should work for you then.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with a combined dictionary and list comprehension:

```
data2 = [{('name' if k == 'attributes' else k): (v['value'] if k == 'attributes' else v) 
         for k, v in di.items()} for di in data]
```

assuming the JSON is stored in `data`. Whether this is obscure or neat compared to a `for` loop is a matter of taste. Also, depending on where the input comes from, you may want to e.g. do some error checking.